# How to read the 'Email' options defined in config/app.php?

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to read the email options defined in `config/app.php`, using `Configure::read('Email');`, but it returns `null`. Other options can be read just fine using `Configure::read(<options name>)`.

I think reading the `Email` options is being blocked somehow. How can I read the `Email` options from the configuration defined in `config/app.php` using `Configure::read()`? Do I maybe have to read them in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Comsumed configuration is being deleted

Some configuration is being "consumed" at some point, by default that currently is `Cache`, `Datasources`, `EmailTransport`, `Email`, `Log`, and `Security.salt`, see your applications `config/bootstrap.php` file.

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.4/config/bootstrap.php#L146-L151**

Consuming keys results in them being deleted after they have been read, so after that point in your bootstrap there will be no `Email` config anymore, and consequently you'll receive `null` when trying to read it.

### Retrieve the configuration from the consumers

If you want to access such configuration at a later point, then you should access it via the classes that consumed it, in your case the `Email` class, ie read it via

```
\Cake\Network\Email\Email::config() // (CakePHP < 3.1)
```

or

```
\Cake\Mailer\Email::config() // (CakePHP >= 3.1)
```

depending on your CakePHP version.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > Configure Class > Reading & Deleting Configuration Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-deleting-configuration-data)**
- **[API > \Cake\Core\Configure::consume()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Core.Configure.html#_consume)**

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP version > 3.4 you have to use

```
\Cake\Mailer\Email::getConfigTransport('smtp');
```